# If the Fourier transform of a function $f$ is real valued then $f$ is an even real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

My lecture notes have a sort of an open ended question in the sense that the question is:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\hat{f}$ be its Fourier transform. If $f$ is real valued what can we say about $\hat{f}$? On the other hand, if we were to know that $\hat{f}$ is real valued, what do we know about $f$?

If $f$ is real valued, then $\overline{\hat{f}(\xi)} = \hat{f}(-\xi)$ as a quick computation will show. I am suspecting that if $\hat{f}$ is real valued, then $f$ must be an even real valued function. My "*rationale*" is that $\overline{\hat{f}(\xi)} = \hat{f}(\xi)\Longleftrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}\overline{f(t)}\overline{\exp(-2\pi itv)}dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\exp(-2\pi itv)dt$

whence if $\overline{f(t)}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(t) = f(-t)$ then we can show the equality quite easily. But I don't know how to even begin showing this more rigorously. Hence my question is:

Is it true that if the Fourier transform of a function is real valued, then the original function is an even real valued function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115021/real-fourier-transform)

Comment: @AnneBauval It does, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at $\overline{f(-t)}$:

$
\overline{f(-t)}=\overline{\int_{ -   \infty  }^{  \infty  } {    F(\omega)   e   ^ {    j    \omega ( -  t )}   } d  \omega} =\int_{ -   \infty  }^{  \infty  } \overline{{    F(\omega)   e   ^ {  -  j    \omega   t }   }} d  \omega =\int_{ -   \infty  }^{  \infty  } {    F(\omega)   e   ^ {    j   \omega    t }   } d  \omega=f(t)
$

$f$ doesn't have to be real.